# Modeling inheritance in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

We are modelling self-referencing entities in MS Dynamics CRM 2015. 
One examples are buildings and part of buildings (Building complex ==> Individual building ==> Entrance ==> Floor ==> Flat).

There are some fields like costcode or owner of the building. 
If you got a building with 300 flats, the whole building might be owned by one company or each flat is owned by individuals.

What we are looking for is some kind of inheritance on field values.
So, for the field "Owner" the user should be able to tick a checkbox that the "owner" is inherited from it's parent record.

We've got about 20 or 30 fields which might be inheritable.

We do want to copy the value from the parent because it makes the definition of views and reports much easier.

Questions: Has this been done before, are there best practices or a finished plugin somewhere?

If I do it myself the solution would be like this:

- For each inheritable field, create a boolean field xx_myfield_inherit
- Put the checkbox and the field always together on the form.
- Create some Javascript magic and plugins:

  - If Checkbox is ticked, put the field in readonly mode and copy value from parent
  - If value is changed, check whether there are children with inheritance set (if done with an onchange trigger, that would probably work recursively, out of the box)
  - ...

There are quite a few special situations to catch (don't allow inheritance, when no parent is set, update inheritance when parent is changed, deselect inheritance, when parent is removed).

I guess that it's perfectly doable but I'd like to get some advice first whether there are better solutions.

Answer (score 5):

30 is a lot of fields to create separate "inherit"-fields for. With respect to usability it's worth to consider grouping of closely related fields.

Doing cascading updates of related records is actually fairly common and I have implemented this kind of functionality often, in most cases for (postal) addresses between accounts, subaccounts and contacts.

Your solution needs to implement the following requirements:

1. When a new record is created, inherited fields must be prefilled.
2. When a parent record's inherited fields are modified, these changes must be synchronized to its child records.
3. When a record is reparented, inherited fields must be updated with its new parent's values. (Unless reparenting should not be possible.)
4. When the parent of a record is removed, inherited fields must either be left as is or be cleared. (It's up to your customer to decide what the desired behaviour is.)
5. When users are able to make records active and inactive, you have a few additional requirements:

   - when a record is made inactive, all of its child records are deactivated too (v.v.).
   - inactive records are not affected by cascading updates.
   - inherited fields must be refreshed when the record is reactivated.

In order to implement these requirements the following custom components are required:

1. A plugin class registered for the following steps:

   - PreValidate synchronous create: this component copies the fields from the parent record.
   - PreValidate synchronous update: this component updates synchronized fields when the record is reparented, when the parental relationship is removed or when an "inherit"-field is modified.
   - PostUpdate asynchronous update: this component updates child records when one or more synchronized fields have been modified.
2. Javascript doing the following:

   - Enable/disable data fields upon OnChange of "inherit"-fields.
   - Get and prefill synchronized field data when you want to provide an optimal user experience.

The only tricky part in this solution is doing the cascading updates in the asynchronous plugin step, mainly because updates are cascaded down the tree and CRM only allows this to happen for 8 levels deep at a maximum (by default).

Also keep in mind that asynchronous plugins running in the sandbox (which is the only option in CRM Online) must complete within 2 minutes. This limit should not be a problem in most cases, because your plugin step will only be responsible for synchronizing changes to the directly related child records.

So, it's possible to design a sound solution here that will perform well. You just need to design a few custom components.

Comment: Excellent answer. The Javascript should be straightforward. We are just starting with plugins, though. Could you imagine to share some of your plugin code to get us started in the right direction? I am sure that your hint with the max propagation level = 8 saved me future headaches. While I hope that we don't exceed 8 levels, it would be great to know a workaround, just in case.

Comment: In CRM Online it will not be easy to work around this limitation. In OnPremise deployments you can modify the MaxDepth setting using either PowerShell or the Dynamics CRM Deployment Service. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531194.aspx#workflow.